# VueJS access to a variable from another method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using **Vuejs** and i would i have two methods one is to make a call and another one is to `hangup`

i would like to access to device variable that i have in `makeCall` methods from `hangup`

error : `Cannot set property 'device' of undefined at eval`

this is my code :

```
    export default {
    components: {Modal},
    data: () => ({
        device: '',
        showModal: false,
        form:{
            output: ''
        },
        collection: {
        }
    }),
    created(){
        
    },
    methods: {
        init(){
            this.showModal = true
        },
        dialer(digit){
            this.form.output += `${digit}`
            this.count++
        },
        clearScreen(){
            let screen = document.getElementById('output').value
            this.form.output = screen.slice(0, -1)
        },
        hangUp(){
          this.device.disconnectAll();
        },
        makeCall(){
            console.log("Requesting Access Token...");
            // Using a relative link to access the Voice Token function
            getAPI.get("api/contacts/token/")
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("Got a token.");
                    console.log("Token: " + response.data.token);

                    // Setup Twilio.Device
                    this.device =  new Twilio.Device(response.data.token, {
                        // Set Opus as our preferred codec. Opus generally performs better, requiring less bandwidth and
                        // providing better audio quality in restrained network conditions. Opus will be default in 2.0.
                        codecPreferences: ["opus", "pcmu"],
                        // Use fake DTMF tones client-side. Real tones are still sent to the other end of the call,
                        // but the client-side DTMF tones are fake. This prevents the local mic capturing the DTMF tone
                        // a second time and sending the tone twice. This will be default in 2.0.
                        fakeLocalDTMF: true,
                        // Use `enableRingingState` to enable the device to emit the `ringing`
                        // state. The TwiML backend also needs to have the attribute
                        // `answerOnBridge` also set to true in the `Dial` verb. This option
                        // changes the behavior of the SDK to consider a call `ringing` starting
                        // from the connection to the TwiML backend to when the recipient of
                        // the `Dial` verb answers.
                        enableRingingState: true,
                        debug: true,
                    });

                    this.device.on("ready", function (device) {
                        console.log("Twilio.Device Ready!");
                    });

                    this.device.on("error", function (error) {
                        console.log("Twilio.Device Error: " + error.message);
                    });

                    this.device.on("connect", function (conn) {
                        console.log('Successfully established call ! ');
                    // $('#modal-call-in-progress').modal('show')
                    });

                    this.device.on("disconnect", function (conn) {
                        console.log("Call ended.");
                    // $('.modal').modal('hide')
                    });

                    var params = {
                      To: document.getElementById('output').value
                    };

                    console.log("Calling me " + document.getElementById('output').value + "...");
                    if (this.device) {
                        var outgoingConnection = this.device.connect(params);
                        outgoingConnection.on("ringing", function () {
                            console.log("Ringing...");
                        });
                    }

                    

                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("Could not get a token from server!");
                });

            }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Define the device variable in the data and then access it using `this.device`.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari already tried but i get an error

Comment: @YashMaheshwari   : Cannot set property 'device' of undefined
    at eval (dialPad.vue?8963:167)
i'm updating my question now

Comment: Try `var self = this` in the makeCall() method and then use `self.device` instead of `this.device`.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to go with above solution, use arrow function when fetching the response from the api.

Comment: same probleme in hangup  method

Comment: @YashMaheshwari the problem in hangup function not in makeCall()

Comment: Where is disconnetAll() defined?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari    disconnectAll()   its a function in Twilio Library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232195/discussion-between-yash-maheshwari-and-alice-munin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to how this works in JS. The function declaration in the promise was creating a different this context than the main function. The `function` keyword sets `this` based on where it is called, whereas arrow functions set `this` based on where it is defined in the code.

All you need to do is replace the `function(response){}` declaration in the getAPI promise `.then` with an arrow function, and it will work fine.

```
makeCall(){
console.log("Requesting Access Token...");
// Using a relative link to access the Voice Token function
getAPI.get("api/contacts/token/")
.then((response) => {
```

Try replacing these lines - to use an arrow function in the .then